# Different bindings of "this" with class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

SOLUTION: I didn't bind the ***stopHandler*** to the instance inside the **constructor**.

---

I defined a class and used it to make the event handler functions and things work different from what I expected.

My class works to render the view of time.
Inside the instance of the class, each data preperties retain values for time (hour, minute, second, etc)
and methods are event handlers.

There are only two buttons; with id of **start** and **stop**, and each of the linked to ***startHandler*** and ***stopHandler***.

To make it iterate, I used *setInterval* and *clearInterval*, so it shows the current time in real time.
To stop showing the time, I have to delete the *setHandler*, so I saved the reference for *setInterval* and used it with *clearInterval* in ***stopHandler*** method.

Here are codes below:

```js
class Timer {
 constructor () {
  this.now = 0
  this.isDayOrNight = ""
  this.hours = 0
  this.minutes = 9
  this.seconds = 0
  this.milliseconds = 0
  this.view = ""

  this.setHandler = this.setHandler.bind(this)
  this.startHandler = this.startHandler.bind(this)
  this.intervalRef
 }

 setHandler() {
  this.now = new Date()
  this.hours = this.now.getHours()
  this.isDayOrNight = (this.hours >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM"
  this.minutes = this.now.getMinutes()
  this.seconds = this.now.getSeconds()
  this.milliseconds = this.now.getMilliseconds()

  this.view = "<p>The time right now: "  + this.isDayOrNight + " " + this.hours + " : " + this.minutes + " : " + this.seconds + " : " + this.milliseconds + "</p>"
  document.getElementById("view").innerHTML = this.view
 }

 startHandler() {
  console.dir(event)
  if (this.view !== "") {
   // clearInterval(this.intervalRef)
   // this.intervalRef = setInterval(this.setHandler, 100)
  }
  else {
   this.intervalRef = setInterval(this.setHandler, 100)
  }
  console.log(this)
  // Timer {now: 0, isDayOrNight: "", hours: 0, minutes: 9, seconds: 0, …}
  console.log(this.intervalRef)
 }

 stopHandler() {
  console.dir(event)
  console.log(this)
  // <button id="stop">STOP</button>
  console.log(this.intervalRef)
  // clearInterval(this.intervalRef)
 }
}

let timer = new Timer()
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", timer.startHandler)
document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", timer.stopHandler)
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Default HTML template</title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="view"></div>
  <button id="start">START</button>
  <button id="stop">STOP</button>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

At this point problem occurs.

I expected the **this** inside the ***stopHandler*** will point to the instance that I made (*new Timer()* ), but it seems this **this** points to the element at which the *"click" event* occured. I could find out this by looking at the console window.

But on the other hand the **this** inside the ***startHandler*** points to the instance that I made, which is as I expected.

Is this okay situation? How do these **this** bind to different things?

Comment: `"click", () => timer.startHandler()`, etc

Comment: Oh I forgot to bind the stopHandler in constructor.